# Spigot API | Player Expand player class

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Is it possible to expand the `Player` class of the `Spigot API` like this:

```
String playername = "PlayerDummy";
Player player = Bukkit.getPlayer(playername);
    if (player.isSuspicious()) {
    // do sth
}
```

can I add the `isSuspicious()` method to the `Player` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in a way that would be useful. Make a static `isSuspicious` method in your own class and do `isSuspicious(player)` instead.

Answer (score -2):

Create a new Player class and then extend the Player Class like this:

```
class PlayerWithSuspicious extends Player{
   ...

   public boolean isSuspicious(){
      return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: But the variable needs to be PlayerWithSuspicious instead of Player?

Comment: Also i do not want to implement all the other mehtods form the Player Interface

Comment: This answer is wrong. Extending a class or implementing an interface doesn't add your new methods to the original, and Spigot's Player objects will be instances of its own class, not yours.